# How would I pass the output of one command to multiple commands?

Tags: command-line, bash

Using process substitution or by grouping & piping , one can pass the output (*stdout*) a set of commands as the input for another command.

Example :

```
wc < <(echo hi;echo bye)
(echo hi; bye) | wc
```

**But is there the opposite ?**

That is, Is there a way to send the output of one command as the input for many other commands in a **single line** ?

Something like :

```
cat testfile | wc | tail -n 5
```

(*Don't take pipelines literally*) . Here I am trying to pass the output of `cat testfile` to both `wc` and `tail -n 5`

Another example would be :

(*to get the last word of a sentence*)

```
echo "some random words"| wc -c | cut -f(out put of wc -c) (output of first echo)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Quick answer.  You can use `tee >(what_to_do) >(another_thing_to_do)` to keep going with your command for as many different things you want to do.

Example:

*Original test file output:*

```
:~$ cat testfile.txt 
Device Model:     LITEONIT LCS-256M6S 2.5 7mm 256GB
Serial Number:    TW0XFJWX550854187616
```

*Output with `tee` commands added:*

```
:~$ cat testfile.txt | tee >(tail -1) >(wc) >(awk '{print $3,$1,$2}')
Device Model:     LITEONIT LCS-256M6S 2.5 7mm 256GB
Serial Number:    TW0XFJWX550854187616
LITEONIT Device Model:
TW0XFJWX550854187616 Serial Number:
      2      10      91
Serial Number:    TW0XFJWX550854187616
```

Each command in tee is just normal commands you would use on the command line, like add in `>(head -1 | wc)` works as well.

```
:~$ cat testfile.txt | tee >(tail -1) >(head -1 | wc)  >(awk '{print $3,$1,$2}')
Device Model:     LITEONIT LCS-256M6S 2.5 7mm 256GB
Serial Number:    TW0XFJWX550854187616
      1       7      52
LITEONIT Device Model:
TW0XFJWX550854187616 Serial Number:
Serial Number:    TW0XFJWX550854187616
```

Or you can also grab the last word of say the last line by using `awk` with `$NF` with a `wc` as well like this:

```
:~$ cat testfile.txt | tail -1 | tee >(wc) >(awk '{print $NF}')
Serial Number:    TW0XFJWX550854187616
TW0XFJWX550854187616
      1       3      39
```

**NOTE:** Adding a `|` pipe command to the end can override using the multiple commands from the `tee` command.  I have some examples here that I have been testing:

*Example 1 (Pipe command pulling all last words):*

```
:~$ echo "This is just five words" | tee >(wc -l) >(wc -w) >(wc -c) | awk '{print $NF}'
words
24
5
1
```

*Example 2 (Does not show the output of the wc commands. Pipe command grabbing 3rd word.):*

```
:~$ echo "This is just five words" | tee >(wc -l) >(wc -w) >(wc -c) | awk '{print $3}'
just
```

*Example 3 (Grabbing the 3rd word of echo line.  Tee command.):*

```
:~$ echo "This is just five words" | tee >(wc -l) >(wc -w) >(wc -c) >(awk '{print $3}')
This is just five words
just
24
5
1
```

*Example 4 (Grabbing the last word of the echo line. Tee command.):*

```
:~$ echo "This is just five words" | tee >(wc -l) >(wc -w) >(wc -c) >(awk '{print $NF}')
This is just five words
words
24
5
1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The statement about the ordering of the output between the various consumers of `tee` is false. The reason you usually get the correct order is that on a low load machine, the first consumer process gets to run first. On a busier machine, the first consumer might be put to sleep before it gets to print anything.

Comment: @MateiDavid I can't prove it otherwise, so I just removed the statement.  No biggie.

Comment: See my answer. But more seriously, `tee` has no idea about the consumers- they are created by `bash` who processes the line. All that `bash` does is to copy the open file descriptors. Beyond that, you have several consumers writing to file descriptors opened on the same file. The kernel takes care of that, but certainly the order they appeared on the `bash` command line won't be a factor.

Answer (score 17):

You need `tee` to split the stream into parts. Try:

```
cat testfile | tee >(wc -l) >(wc -w) >(wc -c) | tail -n 5
```

Notes:

- If multiple processes (`wc`, `tail`) are all writing to stdout:

  - You might get garbled output.
  - There is no guarantee about the order in which their output will appear. To see this, try `sleep 1; wc -w` as the second consumer.
- `tee` will block if any of its destinations does not consume the stream fast enough. Meaning, the destinations will be fed input at roughly similar speed (modulo the fixed-size buffering). There is no easy fix for this, the only alternative is to save the stream to a file, and feed it to the consumers separately. For `wc` and `tail` this is not an issue.

For the last word, it's simpler to do:

```
echo "some random words" | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 6):

The `moreutils` package provides the command `pee` (merge of pipe and tee, what did you think?) which does exactly that.

For your first example, you'd use:

```
cat testfile | pee wc "tail -n 5"
```

The second example is more complicated because you want to pass two inputs to the last command. I would probably use `awk` as the other answers.

Link: https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/

Answer (score 0):

Get only the leading and the trailing parts of a file:

```bash
[wolf]$ cat >foo
1
2
3
4
5
6
^d
[wolf]$ cat foo | tee >(head -2) >(tail -2) >/dev/null
1
2
5
6
```